# MIPS Assembly finding if prime or not

Tags: mips32, mars-simulator

I wrote this code to check if something is a prime number or not.

```
    .data
is_prime:   .asciiz "--Prime--"
not_prime:  .asciiz "--No prime--"
element:    .word 2

    .text
main:
    #importeer prime messages
    la $t3, is_prime
    la $t4, not_prime
    lw $t1, element
    # input variabele n
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

if_loop:
    beq $t0, 1, prime_true
    bgt $t0, 1, prime_check

prime_check:
    beq $t0, $t1, prime_true
    div $t1, $t0
    mfhi $t6
    beq $t6, 0, prime_false
    addi $t0, $t0, 1

prime_true:
    li $v0, 4
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall
    j exit
prime_false:
    li $v0, 4
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall
    j exit
exit:
```

However, every time I run it with any input like 3, 4, 5 or 6 it gives --Prime-- when for 4 and 6 it shouldn't.

Comment: I don't see any jumping back to `if_loop:` so I suppose your code will declare something like `9` to be a prime because you currently only check if a number is divisible by `2`

Comment: You're right, it said that 9 was prime too. Forgot to add that, thanks!

Comment: hmm, still having some hiccups. now it says 3 isn't prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MIPS is quite rusty, but as I understand your code, the value you want to check is in `$t0` and the incrementing divisor is in `$t1`. So your code has the following issues

- `div $t1, $t0`  calculates `$t1 / $t0`. You want to calculate `$t0 / $t1`, so switch the parameters (as you already noticed yourself)
- you are lacking a `j if_loop` somewhere -- probably best after `addi` -- for your loop to continue after you checked the remainder of the division. So for any odd number your code will just continue running straight ahead and print out `"--Prime--"`
- `addi $t0, $t0, 1` is incrementing the value you want to check, instead of the divisor. You have to `addi $t1, $t1, 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for the module part I switched up my two elements.

This was:

```
div $t1, $t0
```

And is supposed to be:

```
div $t0, $t1
```

edit: still having issues, added a jump back to the if_loop after it loops through the prime_check and now it says 3 isn't prime.